# option's css class is removed when option is selected

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<select class="FunctieSelect">
<option class="yellow" value="-1">- kies -</option>
<option class="yellow" value="1">KSZ functie</option>
<option class="yellow" value="2">Bakker</option>
<option class="yellow" value="3">Schilder</option>
<option class="yellow" value="4">Andere</option>
</select>
```

with

```
.yellow
{
    background-color: Yellow;
}
```

produces the following output:

[alt text http://thomasstock.net/selectCss.JPG](http://thomasstock.net/selectCss.JPG)

In reality, only one of the options will have a yellow background, so setting the css on the select is not going to help me

=> How do I make the option stay yellow when it is selected?

I know a possible solution is using jquery to make an "change" event, check in the change event which option is selected, and then set the css of the select. But I wonder if there's an easier solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed with Andrew. One other thing you might think about, though, is that usability goes down when you change form elements' styles. If you mean to denote a changed part of a form you might just highlight the box around the select.

Comment: The grid I'm developing will be used exactly 1 time by a few thousand companies. In the grid they have to change the function/job of their employees.

Comment: One of the functions is the default "to change" function and we want to show that one in yellow, to point out that it still has to be changed using the dropdown. 
Do you have another suggestion on how we could point this out?
I'm thinking my previously mentioned jquery code is the best solution..

Comment: I'm sure the jQuery code would work, I guess I'd rather highlight around the select box by using myselectbox.parentNode.className += " yellow". If you must color the form element itself, then perhaps the jQuery is the way to go.

Comment: The jquery code did not work. Adding the class "yellow" to the select also turned all option's yellow :-)
I will use a parent div as you suggested. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Well if you like you can also add select.yellow option { background-color: #fff; } to your CSS.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately what you are seeing is the browser's default widget behavior that has no CSS override.  There are some options available to you - perhaps something like [Taming the select](http://icant.co.uk/forreview/tamingselect/) will be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to style select box I'd suggest replace them with something like JQuery Flexbox ([demo](http://www.fairwaytech.com/flexbox/Demos.aspx)). If not they will be rendered in different ways across browsers & platforms.